# FactoryGirl InvalidFactoryError NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a card factory (defined below),

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do
    front { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    back { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    tags { Faker::Lorem.words(3).join(';') }

    # associations
    user
    tag
  end
end
```

When I try to run the spec I get the following error,

```
An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.lint

FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError:
  The following factories are invalid:

  * card - undefined method `each' for "eum;et;ad":String (NoMethodError)
```

I have no idea why this is happening, code below is my card model,

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  validates :front, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  has_one :meta_sm2
  has_many :action_records
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  delegate :username, :email, :name,
           to: :user, prefix: true
end
```

Comment: What's `before(:suite)`

Comment: `tags { Faker::Lorem.words(3).join(';') }` expects an array instead of string

Comment: try this. `tags { Faker::Lorem.words(3) }` instead of tags `{ Faker::Lorem.words(3).join(';') }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `card` has `many-many` association with `tags`

`tags` expects an `array`, instead you passed a string,

Try, **`tags { Faker::Lorem.words(3) }`** instead of **`tags { Faker::Lorem.words(3).join(';') }`**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do
    front { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    back { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    tags { Faker::Lorem.words(3) }

    # associations
    user
    tag
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This was not my problem but  your answer combined with another answer led me to what I need thank you :D

Comment: @MikeHeft, I m happy that it got helpful to you. good day. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have an HABTM association between `cards` and `tags`. I don't really get how can you set `tags` with just an array or a string instead of associated objects but still I believe you want to set up correct HABTM association in your factories and one can do that like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do
    front { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    back { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    # tags { Faker::Lorem.words(3).join(';') }

    # associations
    user


    factory :card_with_tags do
      after(:create) do |book|
        create_list(:tag, 3, cards: [card])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It's the "lighweight" way to set up HABTM in the factories. I've mentioned the "thorough" way in the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787522/habtm-association-with-factorygirl/41790014#41790014) of my recent answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by change the factory code to the code below,

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do
    front { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    back { Faker::Lorem.sentence }

    # associations
    user
    tag
    meta_sm2
    action_record
  end
end
```

I think the previous issue is related to the missing associations.